# How to popup window in a callback

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, popup

I have a javascript application, which authenticates user through social network (with a popup, that is closed after user authentication) API, and then, in some specific cases, pops up a 'repost' window. API is completely asynchronous and popup should be created in callback. However, Chrome's policy is to block all popups that aren't called in handler itself (but in other functions). Is there any approach I can use to popup that second window? 
P.S. Social network is vk.com, if that can help/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, as the API blocks all calls not originating from a click event.

I would recommend using a [modal popup instead](http://www.bootply.com/61676#) if you're going in this route.